# output is not displayed for python gui program on eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I have copied below code from http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/. when I execute it on python 3.5 with eclipse luna 4.4.0 editor, it seems run successfully but did not display any output. How do I fix this?

```
import tkinter

class simpleapp(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk._init_(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initilize()

    def initialize(self):
        pass
if __name__ == '_main_':
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('Topic Modeling for Gujarati Text')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It should be `'__main__'`, not `'_main_'`

Comment: Thank you. It works now.